# What's the difference between “ terror attack” and " terrorist attack"

Tags: meaning, expressions, semantics

Both of the expressions are commonly seen on the media.
What is the difference in meaning?

Comment: They mean the same thing. A terrorist commits a terror attack. Or, a terrorist commits a terrorist attack.

Comment: Please give some examples.  You say it is common, so it should be easy to find some a couple of examples of each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is perhaps a slight difference.

It's implied that a terrorist commits a **terrorist attack**. The classic definition of a terrorist is someone who is motivated by ideological beliefs, and often part of an organization like the Irish Republican Army (IRA) or Al-Qaeda.

That implication doesn't necessarily exist with a **terror attack**, so it can be applied a little more broadly. For example, you can say that a serial killer is on a terror spree/rampage/attack, but he probably wouldn't be considered a terrorist.

Comment: Some might add right-wing extremists and anti-abortionists who shoot people in the group of people 'motivated by ideological beliefs'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - definitely, but while a terrorist attack would be ideologically motivated by definition, the serial killer's terror attack might not be (despite the media's more frequent application to political acts).

Comment: @ItWasLikeThatWhenIGotHere - Maybe usages differ, I live in the UK, but if I killed a number of people at (e.g) a mosque, synagogue, abortion clinic, government building, Covid vaccination centre, or in the street, because of my 'beliefs', the tabloid press might well headline it 'Terror attack at _location_' but if I killed them because 'the voices' told me to, or simply because I felt like it, they probably would not.